# Jquery and localStorage how to add more elements to the site clipdoard/cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

i'm studying jquery with localStorage and want to create somekind of page clipboard tab where you can add product, pictrures etc. to view it later.

This is my jquery code:

```
var count = 0;
jQuery('.add_rem').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('remove')) {
      count -= 1;
    }else {
      count += 1;
    }     
    jQuery.each( function(){
      if(jQuery(this).hasClass('remove')){
          if(count == 0) {
            jQuery('.list li.empty').show();
          }
          if($(".remove").attr('id') == localStorage.getItem('id') ) {
              localStorage.removeItem('id');
              $("#"+localStorage.getItem('id')).removeClass('remove');
          }
      } else {
          jQuery('.list li.empty').hide();
          localStorage.setItem('count', count);
          localStorage.setItem('id', jQuery(this).attr('id'));
          if(jQuery(this).attr('id') == localStorage.getItem('id')){
            jQuery(".add_rem#"+localStorage.getItem('id')).addClass("remove"); 
          }
          localStorage.setItem('link', jQuery('.link').attr('href'));
          localStorage.setItem('photo', jQuery('.photo').attr('src'));
          localStorage.setItem('name', jQuery('b.name').text());
        jQuery('#hp-content .wrapper .list').append('<li><a href="'+ localStorage.getItem('link') +'"> <img src="'+ localStorage.getItem('photo') +'" alt="photo" /><br />'+ localStorage.getItem('name') +' </a></li>');
        jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
      }
    jQuery('.panel2 a span').text('('+ localStorage.getItem('count') +')');
 })
})
```

This is the HTML code of one product:

```
<tr>
  <td class="nul">
   <a href="javascript:;" class="add_rem"><img src="/img/check_of.png" alt="Add / remove from clipboard" title="add to clipboard"></a>
  </td>
  <td class="nul">
   <a href="13/test/" class="link">
     <img class="photo" alt="Test" src="images/pl/brak.gif">
   </a>
  </td>
  <td class="nul"><b>Test1 / kk</b></td>
  <td class="nul"><i>Princeton</i></td>
  <td class="nul">College</td>
  <td class="nul">
    <a href="13/test/">
     <img alt="Show" src="images/general/show.gif">
    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </td>
 </tr>
```

This is HTML of clipboard:

```
<div style="" id="clipboard">
  <div class="panels">
    <ul>
      <li class="panel2"><a href="#">Clipboard <span>(0)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="hp-content"><div id="clipboard-bg">
        <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="list"> 
       <li class="empty"><strong>Empty.</strong><span class="one">The clipboard is now empty.</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but after page reload all copied elements are erased

Comment: start getting a bunch of cookies going might start considering loaclStorage instead. Every cookie you create has to be sent with every http request made to server, are limited in qty per domain and also limted in size. Can stringify big objects and arrays quickly into localStorage

Comment: so how can i alternatively do this?? add it to database or what?? i'm stuck in this moment and can't go further i have no idea how to do this :( a little help?? how can i create an array in cookie?

Comment: read about localStorage.... just holds more than cookie. Very simple to use, don't even need a plugin for it

Comment: ok i'm reading but there is other problem how to add more than one element i have no idea how to design this loop or other function

Comment: create a simplified demo in jsfiddle.net. Not sure where you are adding data from, might be easier to visualize. Switch images for text

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pLPuW/1/ the pictrue im getting from the element in the table

Answer (score 2):

I have a local storage jQuery plugin you could use: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/localstorage/. But local storage is so incredibly simple that you don't even need that plugin. Here are a few functions I have written for you:

Note this is basically a small javascript library: (`LS = LocalStorage`)

```
(function(){
    var LS = function(){
        return new LS.fn.init();
    };
    LS.fn = LS.protorype ={
        //Check to see if the browser suports LocalStorage
        init : function(){
            this.ls = (typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") ? false : true;
            return this;
        }
    }
    LS.fn.init.prototype = LS.fn;
    LS.fn.init.prototype = {
        set : function(name, val){
            if(this.ls) localStorage.setItem(name, val);
        },
        get : function (name){
            if(this.ls) return localStorage.getItem(name);
        },
        remove : function(name){
            if(this.ls) localStorage.removeItem(name);
        }
    }
    window.LS = window._ = LS;
})()
```

Tiny documentation for this library.

**Set:** Sets the value of local storage data. Ex:

```
LS().set("Foo", "bar");
--OR--
_().set("Foo", "bar");
```

---

**Get:** Gets the value of local storage data. Ex:

```
LS().get("Foo")//returns "bar"
--OR--
_().get("Foo")
```

---

**Remove:** Removes local storage data. Ex:

```
LS().remove("Foo");
--or--
_().remove("Foo");
```

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: thanks this is good start for me :) but can you tell me how to add multiple elements you know if i'll have two rows in table and i want to add both as two li elements to clipboard  ?? eg. `<li>element1</li><li>element2</li>`

Comment: after refresh page all data are erased :(

Comment: @arclite Hmm... That's a problem. Are you getting any errors in the console? What is your code?

Comment: There are no errors in console and i modified the code in my question to use localStorage but not in your function cause it wan't to fire in script with Smarty library

Comment: i can't store the variables any ideas??